# laravel -how to logout session after checking remember me on a custom guard?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I created a custom guard in laravel the problem i am having with the custom guard is that when i check the remember me function on the login page, i can login in but when i want to sign out i can not terminate the session. I know that the problem is in the logout functionality but not sure how to fix the issue. I tried to copy the logout function in the `authenticatesuser.php` but still wasn't able to terminate the session and log out.

logincontroller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\CustomerAuth;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    protected function guard()
    {
        return Auth()->guard('customer');
    }

    public function logoutcustomer()
    {
    $customer =  Auth::guard($customer)->logout();
        $customer->session()->invalidate();
        return redirect('/');
    }



    public function showLoginForm()
    {
        if (Auth::user() || Auth::guard('customer')->user()) {
            return redirect('/');
        } else {
            return view('customer-auth.login');
        }
    }
}
```

---

AuthenticatesUser.php

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->session()->invalidate();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

---

```
//navbar customer

<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('customer.logout') }}" onclick="event.preventDefault();
                                                 document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                                    {{ __('Logout') }}
                                </a>
                        <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('customer.logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                            @csrf
                        </form>
```

---

web route

```
Route::group(['prefix'=> 'customer'], function () {
// Login Routes...
    // Route::get('login', ['as' => 'customer.login', 'uses' => 'CustomerAuth\LoginController@showLoginForm']);

    Route::post('login', [ 'uses' => 'CustomerAuth\LoginController@login'])->name('customer.login');
    // Route::post('logout', ['as' => 'customer.logout', 'uses' => 'CustomerAuth\LoginController@logoutcustomer']);
    Route::post('logout', 'CustomerAuth\LoginController@logoutcustomer')->name('customer.logout');

}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @SteveNosse when i want to logout with the custom guard i can't logout when i check the remember me button to login

Comment: may be you should manually delete the remember token of the authenticated user before login him out ? Did you try this ?

Comment: @SteveNosse i haven't tried that how would i do that i have a  logoutcustomer function in the  logincontroller i posted

Comment: Try : `$user = Auth::user(); $user->remember_token = ""; $user->save();` in your logoutcustomer function before doing `Auth::guard("custom")->logout();`

Comment: @SteveNosse nope did not work i am still logged iin

Answer (score 2):

As a newbie, I was facing the same problem too. I added that logout function down below  into LoginController.php file. Adding a new line for each guard solved my problem. I'm sure there is better way to write those two guards together, but this is what I can do.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
    {
        Auth::guard('customer')->logout();
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->flush();
        $request->session()->regenerate();
        return redirect('/');
    }
```

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a
              class="nav-link logout"
              href="{{ route('logout') }}"
              onclick="event.preventDefault();
                       document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                       <i class="fas fa-power-off"></i>
                       <p>{{ __('Logout') }}</p>
            </a>
            <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                @csrf
            </form>
          </li>
```

Comment: hey i think there something with my logout when i dd logout it uses the auth::user() logout instead of the custom one i made not sure if there a issue on my navbar or a issue with my route i updated my post added the route and navbar @BülentAkgül

Comment: I edited my answer and add the code my logout button. I think it is default codes. BTW, I followed that tutorial (https://www.pusher.com/tutorials/multiple-authentication-guards-laravel/). Can you check this one please, it's very clean.

Comment: got it working thank you took me months to figure this out @BülentAkgül

Answer (score 1):

```
    Try This:

   public function guard() {   
      return Auth::guard('customer');
    }

    public function logoutcustomer(){
       $this->guard()->logout();
       return redirect('/');
    }
```

Comment: @SanjayKhadka i just tried it and when i tried to logout the i couldn't log out of that guard

Comment: @jmike whats the error ? This works fines for me . By logging out of the guard it works .

Comment: @HarshPatel sorry i am just new here . My Code was just modified from jmike's code . The function logoutcustomer method logout the customer using the guard 'customer' .

Comment: You can write what's the modification you did and why.

Comment: @SanjayKhadka hey so i think i know my problem i tried to dd my logout request and it turns out its not using the custom logout function but it still using the AuthenticateUser.php logout function so something wrong with my form in navbar